# How to measure geometry efficiently in Google Map

Tags: google-maps-api-3, leaflet, openstreetmap, geojson

I would like to add color to each house in the following google map example:

https://www.google.com/maps/@43.0748326,141.3479359,19z?hl=en

I found an example in leaflet that add colors to US states by giving the GeoJson data including the corners coordinates of each state. You can find the example here:

http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html

I would like to do it with Google Map. Two questions in front of me are:
1. How can I get the corner coordinates of houses?
2. As the number of houses which I want to add color is relatively large, how can I efficiently measure the corner coordinates of these houses?

Comment: Ok this is very confusing. You're either using the Google Maps library OR your using the Leaflet library. What do you mean by "add color to each house in the following google map example using leaflet"? You want to use Leaflet and do the same thing as in that example?

Comment: @iH8. I don't know the best way to achieve my goal. I have seen people using leaflet with Google Map. I will modify my question a little.

Comment: Perhaps you mean people using the Leaflet library and showing Google maptiles? Or do you mean using the Google maps library and combining that with Leaflet somehow? (Which i've never seen in my life) Could you otherwise give some examples where "people are using leaflet with google map"?

Comment: @iH8  I mean the first case. You can find the example here: https://gist.github.com/crofty/2197701

Answer (score 0):

> 1. How can I get the corner coordinates of houses?

You can't. The data in Google Maps API is not available to you, because of technical and legal restrictions.

You'll likely want to do this some other way: for instance, with [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) data and one of the many services that visualizes it.